# Amdahl's law to determine the overall speed increase using the optimizations

Tags: computer-architecture

There is an old CPU running a program in which memory operations
currently take 30% of its execution time. Scientists find that adding a cache memory
speeds up 80% of memory operations by a factor of 6. Adding a second level of cache
speeds up half of the remaining 20% by a factor of 3. By how much does the overall speed
increase using these optimizations?

Comment: This is an exercise, right? We won't help you if you don't show that you have at least tried to answer the question. You have at first two boxes for the CPU : 70% of non memory, and 30% memory. Then, inside the 30% memory accesses, you have the 20% of non accelerated and 80% of accelerated. CPU execution time is something like : 0.7 + 0.3*(0.8+0.2). Then you accelerate some parts...